# Copper powder amount dissoved in water

Tags: aqueous-solution

How much copper powder dispersed into 2 liters of water will result in a 10 ppm concentration? I am not a chemist.

Comment: Adding copper powder to water won't result in a homogeneous solution and there is no concentration to speak of since copper solubility in water is negligible.

Comment: However if you manage to disperse it, it amounts to 0.00002 g. It is the term "dissolved" that isn't correct. Or it can be in ionic form. For the calculation, at this high dilution we consider the density of solution equal to that of water,  so calculate ppm is straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

If you want 10 ppm copper in 2 liters of water, the best way to make it would be to start with some soluble copper salt, like $\ce{CuSO4.5H2O}$, make up a convenient concentration (like 1%), then dilute it to 10 ppm.

As was mentioned in the comments, copper metal is not noticeably soluble in water. When rainwater washing thru copper downspouts leaves a blue stain on concrete, the copper metal is dissolving because of tiny solubility of copper oxides or carbonates. It might be 10 ppm, or 1 ppm in a lot more water.